# How to parse OpenWeatherMap 16-day json?

Tags: java, android, json, openweathermap

Hi I'm trying to create an android application that will display the weather from opneweathermap. So far I have the application displaying today's weather, but I'm not able to parse 16-day JSON. I am trying to get the min and max temp of each of the days. Any help will be appreciated.

> {"cod":"200","message":0.4667,"cnt":7,"list":[{"dt":1512777600,"main":{"temp":0.71,"temp_min":0.71,"temp_max":5.21,"pressure":1030.25,"sea_level":1035.12,"grnd_level":1030.25,"humidity":100,"temp_kf":-4.5},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":8.86,"deg":304.5},"rain":{},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2017-12-09 00:00:00"},{"dt":1512788400,"main":{"temp":1.35,"temp_min":1.35,"temp_max":4.72,"pressure":1029.09,"sea_level":1034,"grnd_level":1029.09,"humidity":100,"temp_kf":-3.38},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":8.07,"deg":292},"rain":{},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2017-12-09 03:00:00"},{"dt":1512799200,"main":{"temp":2.21,"temp_min":2.21,"temp_max":4.46,"pressure":1027.47,"sea_level":1032.37,"grnd_level":1027.47,"humidity":100,"temp_kf":-2.25},"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02n"}],"clouds":{"all":24},"wind":{"speed":7.66,"deg":280.001},"rain":{},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2017-12-09 06:00:00"},{"dt":1512810000,"main":{"temp":3.35,"temp_min":3.35,"temp_max":4.47,"pressure":1025.64,"sea_level":1030.48,"grnd_level":1025.64,"humidity":100,"temp_kf":-1.13},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"clouds":{"all":48},"wind":{"speed":6.69,"deg":275.001},"rain":{},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2017-12-09 09:00:00"},{"dt":1512820800,"main":{"temp":5.02,"temp_min":5.02,"temp_max":5.02,"pressure":1023.2,"sea_level":1028.06,"grnd_level":1023.2,"humidity":100,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":{"all":68},"wind":{"speed":6.12,"deg":266},"rain":{},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2017-12-09 12:00:00"},{"dt":1512831600,"main":{"temp":5.29,"temp_min":5.29,"temp_max":5.29,"pressure":1019.44,"sea_level":1024.28,"grnd_level":1019.44,"humidity":100,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"clouds":{"all":44},"wind":{"speed":4.76,"deg":266.002},"rain":{},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2017-12-09 15:00:00"},{"dt":1512842400,"main":{"temp":4.54,"temp_min":4.54,"temp_max":4.54,"pressure":1016.14,"sea_level":1021.07,"grnd_level":1016.14,"humidity":100,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":3.37,"deg":254.504},"rain":{},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2017-12-09 18:00:00"}],"city":{"id":2964574,"name":"Dublin","coord":{"lat":53.344,"lon":-6.2672},"country":"IE"}}

```
private void renderWeather(JSONObject json)
{
    /*
    //minField.setText(json.toString());

    try
    {
        JSONArray resultArray = json.getJSONArray("list");
        for(int i = 0; i < resultArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject obj = resultArray.getJSONObject(i);
            //store your variable
            String tempMin = obj.getString("temp_min");
            Log.i("TAG","Temp Min " + i + ": "+ tempMin);
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    */

    String yourJsonString = json.toString();

    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    try
    {
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(yourJsonString);

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject obj1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONArray results = obj1.getJSONArray("list");
            String tempMin =  results.getJSONObject(0).getString("temp_min");
            Log.i("TAG","Temp Min " + i + ": "+ tempMin);
        }
    }

    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I've tried the two ways shown in the code and neither work. The first way gets a JSONException: No value for temp_min error. The second way gets a JSONException: Value error.

Comment: The code commented out should work except temp_min value is not a string value, it's a number. Use obj.getDouble("temp_min") instead of obj.getString("temp_min");
Edit: The second code doesn't work because what you have there is not a JSONArray, it's a JSONObject which has a JSONArray as the value for the key "list".

Comment: Hi I changed the line to Double tempMin = obj.getDouble("temp_min"); and it gives an error: org.json.JSONException: No value for temp_min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you get a blob of JSON data that you can't immediately understand, first try to run it through a beautifier (aka formatter) to see the structure.

I uploaded your JSON into this only JSON formatter:

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

and below is the result. Now you can start making sense of it.

[image]

It looks like the outline block below represents one day. Write your code accordingly to parse it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look at the structure of what you have to work with, starting from the top:
You have a JSONObject which has 5 fields. Key "cod" which holds a string value of "200", key "message" which has a numeric value of 0.4667, key "cnt" which has a numeric value of 7, key "list" which has a value which is a JSONArray, and key "country" which holds a string value of "IE". That is the outermost JSON object. from that you want to parse the JSONArray value from the key "list". So far, you're good! But if you look at each one of the JSONObjects in the JSONArray, you'll see that the second key in each one, "main", the value for it is another JSONObject! It gets better, because "weather" holds a JSONArray which only has one JSONObject in it for the first one, but by being an array you can figure that it may hold more than one object so you have to iterate through that too. It's going to be a bit involved, but is doable, you just have to look closely at what the expected format is and correctly identify the parts.

Answer (score 0):

[Please look the controller code in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58568600/is-there-any-better-or-optimize-way-to-return-the-view-with-model-in-controller)

First get the response, if positive then deserialize and then use json conversion in java syntax.